# Is it possible to assign single linq query result to more than one variable?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I can do this in TSQL

```
SELECT
    @TotalDays = COUNT(Days),
    @TotalHours = SUM(Hours)
FROM
    Schedule
WHERE
    GroupID = 1
```

How to achieve this in linq in single query, my current code;

```
var totalDays = 0;
var totalHours = 0;

totalDays = _schedule.Count(c => c.GroupID == 1);
totalHours = _schedule.Where(w => w.GroupID == 1).Sum(s => s.Hours);
```

This is not effective because it call 2 separate queries in the database

Comment: To the title: "Yes"; but that isn't what is really desired with the shown code..

Comment: Do you want a single LINQ query or a single database query?

Comment: I want a single database call, not multiple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var result = _schedule.Where(s => s.GroupID == 1)
                      .GroupBy(x => x.GroupID)
                      .Select(gr => new
                      {
                          TotalDays = gr.Count(),
                          TotalHours = gr.Sum(s=>s.Hours);
                      });
```

Initially, you filter your data based on the `GroupID`. You pick those with `GroupID` equals to 1. Then you `GroupBy` them by their ID. This mihgt seams a bit silly, but this way you create a group of your data. So then you count just count the item in the group and calculate the sum you want. Last but not least after having made the `GroupBy`, you select an anonymous type with two properties, one for the `TotalDays` and one for the `TotalHours`.

Then you can consume the above result as below:

```
var totalDays = 0;
var totalHours = 0;
var first = result.FirstOrDefault();
if(first!=null)
{
    totalDays = first.TotalDays,
    totalHours = first.TotalHours
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem, sometimes, trying to make a single LINQ query is that it actually gets translated into multiple database calls. Sometimes it is better to pull all of your raw data into memory in a single database call and then perform the calculations.

This will ensure only one database call:

```
var data = _schedule.Where(w => w.GroupID == 1).Select(w => w.Hours).ToArray();

var totalDays = data.Count();
var totalHours = data.Sum();
```

The key to making this work is the `.ToArray()` which forces the evaluation of the database query. If there are a lot of items this call can become inefficient, but in lot of cases it is still very fast.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the next code

```
 //one request to data base
    var lstResult=_schedule.Where(w => w.GroupID == 1).ToArray();
    //one loop in array for Count method
    totalDays = lstResult.Count();
    //One loop in array for Sum method
    totalHours = lstResult.Sum(s => s.Hours);
```